# When I switch git branches in xcode are framework versions preserved?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have an xcode project where I maintain a separate branch for each release - for example, a 2.0.5 branch and then a 2.0.6 branch.

When I was developing in the newer branch, I upgraded to a newer version of an SDK I was dependent on.

I assumed that when I switched back to 2.0.5, ran the app, and switched to 2.0.6 and ran the app, it would test the transition between the two versions of the framework. I see in the version history that the new framework files are added to the project.

However, when I switch back and forth, select the framework in xcode, and select "show in finder" it appears to be the same binary. I'm a bit confused - does git actually maintain two different versions of the framework or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it maintains two different versions. This is the purpose of source control systems.